# Rails Custom Validations on Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, associations

I have a user. A user can have many tables. Actual, only 5.

In my table model I have

```
validate :max_tables

def max_tables
 if user.tables.count > 5
  errors[:base] << "You already have 5 tables."
 end
end
```

This works all good and if I try to create a table and my user already has 5, I get a page that says

> ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid in TablesController#create
>
> Validation failed: You already have 5 tables.

But I don't get redirected back to the new table page with errors displaying nicely like I do if other validations aren't met. For some reason I'm getting stuck on this hard error page.

Any ideas?

## EDIT: SOLVED

I was generating a short url in an after_create callback, and in there I was calling `save!`

Once I fixed that, All was good. So thanks @house9!

Comment: Btw, I think you should simply return false after adding the error to base

Comment: `return false` doesn't do anything for me.

Comment: are you calling save or save! in your controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: SOLVED
I was generating a short url in an after_create callback, and in there I was calling save!

Once I fixed that, All was good. So thanks @house9!

Answer (score 0):

Use `errors.add_to_base "You already have 5 tables."` - in my oldest and biggest app I use `errors.add_to_base` and `return false` - it could be that the return is not required, but I haven't tested it.